# .click() works in firefox but not in chrome

Tags: jquery

I use the solution suggested in the answer to this question

[How to make twitter bootstrap tab as form wizard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426872/how-to-make-twitter-bootstrap-tab-as-form-wizard)

because I need the same functionality and it works great in firefox but in chrome I get:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object.../localhost:..../#otherIncome1 has no method 'click'`

I am aware that `.click()` on elements isn't supported in chrome (or am I wrong?).
 I've found related questions but nothings seems to work.

I've tried:
`"$('#n.1').click()"` or `"$('#n.1').trigger('click')"`

I get no errors but still doesn't work.
Any hints?

Comment: Usually happens if you copy-paste the code, because of special invisible characters.

Comment: how did you attach you click event to "#n.1" ? maybe you could create a simple fiddle.net example?

Comment: what do you mean?so what I should do?then it would also not work in firefox,or?

Comment: @Dappergoat the code exists in the link I provide, there's no reason to duplicate it I think

Comment: so you copied the code from "how to make twitter bootstrap..." and replaced the "document.getelementbyid" with $("#id-to-select")?
Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/350292/how-do-i-get-jquery-to-select-elements-with-a-period-in-their-id and read the part about special characters in jquery selectors. I think it could be the '.' in the ID that messes up your code.

Comment: forget what I changed. I tried the initial code and it worked in firefox but not in chrome(despite of the dot in the id). Any ideas how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that I found a solution that works in both chrome and firefox.
I used the code in the first answer to this question:
[How to simulate a mouse click using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157929/how-to-simulate-mouse-click-using-javascript)

combined with:

```
 $("#b1n").click(function ()
   {
    simulate(document.getElementById("n.2"), "click");
   });
 $("#b2n").click(function ()
   {
    simulate(document.getElementById("n.3"), "click");
   });
```

...for all the buttons
and also changed the buttons in this way:
from this:

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('n.2').click()">next</button>
```

to this:

```
 <button id='b2n'>next</button>
```

and..that's all!